# Google app conversion tracking sdk with swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics-sdk

how can i integrate google conversion tracking sdk with swift 1.2. 
https://developers.google.com/app-conversion-tracking/ios/?hl=en_US

I tried add .h file in bridge-header file but i cant access ACTReporter in appdelegate. Any idea how to integrate this

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: ACTAutomatedUsageTracker.enableAutomatedUsageReportingWithConversionID("CONVERSION_ID")
        
        ACTConversionReporter.reportWithConversionID("CONVERSION_ID", label: "XXX", value: "0.00", isRepeatable: false)

Comment: Solution here works for me in swift 2. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36136563/346676