# google adwords conversion tracking with swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-ads-api

I am trying to get google adwords working on a swift project I have followed https://developers.google.com/app-conversion-tracking/ios/ and have had no results. Keeps saying no such module "ACTReporter"

Does anyone have any info?

Comment: So, what did you do until now?

Comment: I've used it on obj-c projects in the past, but can't for the life of me to get it to work on Swift.

Comment: I mean what did you do until now to get it working in this current project. Each step.

Comment: downloaded and imported the SDK. Added -ObjC as a other Linker Flags. Added libGoogleConversionTracking.a and adsupport.framework to link binary with libraries. Then tried importing ACTReporter

Comment: Its not telling me I need one upon import. I thought that that was less of an issue in swift 2.0

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @plaidpancakes If you have found Any solution/works plz update. will be helpful

Answer (score 14):

This is possible in Swift using the usual bridging header routine. You can [add the SDK to your project manually](https://developers.google.com/app-conversion-tracking/ios/) or use the [GoogleConversionTracking](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleConversionTracking) pod.

Just add the pod to your podfile:

```
pod 'GoogleConversionTracking'
```

and then add the following to your [bridging header](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html):

```
#import <GoogleConversionTracking/ACTReporter.h>
```

And finally, in your AppDelegate.swift file (with the correct ID and label):

```
// Google Conversion Tracking
ACTAutomatedUsageTracker.enableAutomatedUsageReportingWithConversionID("0123456789")
ACTConversionReporter.reportWithConversionID("0123456789", label: "XXXXXX", value: "0.00", isRepeatable: false)
```

Comment: Thanks! For enableAutomatedUsageReportingWithConversionID is the value just the App's ID? Because Adwords didn't give me a conversion ID, at least as far as I can see.

Comment: You'll need to set up conversion tracking within your AdWords account (see [here](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722054)). The relevant instructions for setting up conversion tracking for iOS can be found [here](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6095881). If you follow that guide, you'll be presented with some example code towards the end, and you can use the conversion ID that is shown. Hope that helps!